# Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1, changed state to down

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, intranet

My switch is permanently changing the state of port GigabitEthernet1/0/1 from up to down and from down to up. What can I do?

Console Output:
[image]

Port configuration:
[image]

Sorry, I have only these pictures.
I'm using a Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! My router is a **FRITZ!Box 6690 Cable** with four LAN ports. One of these is for a 2.5Gbps link that the switch was plugged into.

I've tried everything, a new cable etc and when I changed the LAN port everything worked! I don't know why, but the switch couldn't work properly with that port.

Answer (score 3):

Start by replacing the cable connected to the port with a new one. If the problem persists, check other hardware components. Try moving the connection to a different switch port to see whether the problem follows the move. If it doesn't, consider the switch port defective. If it does, check the equipment on the other end.